# I set CSS styles in module.css of my nextjs application, but it don't work

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I created a nextjs with electron template application:

my code as here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sx6qfm

I set CSS classes in `VscodeLayout.module.css`:

```
.container {
  width: '100%';
  height: '100%'
}

.header {
  height: '28px';
  width: '100%';
  background-color: '#00d9'
}


.leftBar {
  background-color: '#0031'
}

.navBar {
  background-color: '#00f3'
}

.content {

}

.rightBar {
  background-color: '#00f3'
}


.footer {
  height: '22px';
  background-color: '#3370b7'
}
```

but when I run the demo my module css do not work:

[image]

please help with this, why module css don't work there?

Comment: Why are there quotation marks?

Comment: CSS does not require values to be in quotation marks, this looks like a typo from using JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lies with the quotation marks. Please update the CSS without using any quotation marks.

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
  }
  
  .header {
    height: 28px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00d9
  }
  
  
  .leftBar {
    background-color: #0031
  }
  
  .navBar {
    background-color: #00f3
  }
  
  .content {
  
  }
  
  .rightBar {
    background-color: #00f3
  }
  
  
  .footer {
    height: 22px;
    background-color: #3370b7
  }
```

You can utilize regex in VS Code to perform a replacement using the pattern `'(.*)'`  to `$1`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All classes from your css shouldn't have quotation marks:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.header {
  height: 28px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00d9
}
```

And so on.. It should work